# How to merge "Contribution Calendar" between two accounts?

Tags: github, merge, record, github-enterprise

Is there a way to merge the Contribution Calendar between company github enterprise and public personal github account?

Comment: public personal GitHub account is open to all. Anyone can see what is in that repo, is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: This isn't available.